# How to test the performance of ORM/SQL libraries?

Tags: java, sql, performance, orm, persistence

I'm a Java developer and currently I was requested by my manager to evaluate Java ORM and SQL library (such as Hibernate, MyBatis, iBatis, JOOQ, DbUtils, and so on). I would like to run the test to compare the performance between the ORM libraries, and also the performance between the SQL library. However, I have no idea how to write the test case to evaluate their performance.

I found some articles are comparing the performance of 4 CRUD operations for different libraries, but I couldn't get its test case source code. I would like to have it as a reference.

Appreciate if anyone can share with me how to test the performance of the ORM and SQL library.

Note: The performance test is just part of my evaluation. I understand each library is designed for different purpose and I shouldn't compare them merely by their performance.

Thank you very much

Comment: If anything at all, you'll be comparing apples and oranges when you compare ORMs with SQL APIs for performance. Just be sure that you don't simply translate queries from one API to another, because there's an entirely different mind set / architecture style depending on the framework you're using. Or better: You're going to use one or the other framework *because* you're preferring one or the other mind set / architecture style